# Is it necessary to describe co-authorship in research proposal?

Tags: research-process, research-proposal

I am writing a research proposal for a possible university visit. I intend to also mention my recent publication where I am the first author. This led me to the question: Suppose I am writing a research plan, and I am the first/second/n-th author, is it fine to write "my recent paper titled..." instead of "my recent paper co-authored with...", as I also have to keep in mind the word limit. Will it be offensive to not mention the person I worked with in that paper?

Comment: Don't worry about it too much. Buffy's answer is great, but English "my" certainly encompasses things that are shared with other people. Just using "our" could be confusing without clear antecedents.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and honest solution is to just describe "our recent paper" rather than "my recent paper". The list of authors will make it clear without more words. Or adding a few words, "the paper I recently co-authored..." would make it clear.

Just list the paper along with the author listing as published.

But you don't need to explain the specifics of the contributions, especially in a case like this. The author list is sufficient and if the field thinks author order is important for some reason, that list spells it out.

You might be asked to explain more about your contributions during the visit so be prepared for that.